# Returning a Object from filter back to resource

Tags: java, rest, jersey, cxf, wso2

I am currently developing a REST webservice that uses a filter in order to handle the authentication (JWT token). The filter works fine but i am unable to return an object back to the resource (The object contains information about domain access and admin id). 
The environment is CXF, Jersey, Jackson(JSON REST) running on a WSO2 application server version 5.3.0

I was using the `ContainerRequestContext` approach but I am getting a `NullPointerException` every time I try to access the context in my resource code. I have made a simple test case webservice to specifically try the object returning, but this also gets a `NullPointerException` in the resource code. Keep in mind the `ContainerRequestContext` does work in the filter code; I tested this earlier with console debugging.

See below for the code I am using now.
All help is greatly appreciated.

ContextTest.java

```
package test.codehq.fab1.contexttest.cxf3test1;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ResourceContext;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.GenericEntity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/")
@Produces("application/json")
public class ContextTest
{
    @Context
    ResourceContext resourceContext;

    ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext;

    public ContextTest()
    {

    }

    @AuthorizationNeededInterface
    @GET
    @Path("/echos/{echoRequestText}")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response echo(@PathParam("echoRequestText") String echoRequestText)
    {
        System.out.println("DEBUG: IN RESOURCE");

        Map<String, String> myResponse = new HashMap<String, String>();

        containerRequestContext = resourceContext.getResource(ContainerRequestContext.class);

        if(containerRequestContext != null)
        {
            if(containerRequestContext.getProperty("AuthID") != null)
            {
                if(((String)containerRequestContext.getProperty("AuthID")).compareTo("1234") == 0)
                {
                    myResponse.put("echo_response", echoRequestText);
                } 
                else myResponse.put("echo_response", "Invalid AuthID <1>");
            } 
            else myResponse.put("echo_response", "Invalid AuthID <2>");
        }
        else myResponse.put("echo_response", "Invalid AuthID <3>");

        GenericEntity<Map<String, String>> genericEntity = new GenericEntity<Map<String, String>>(myResponse){};
        return Response.ok().entity(genericEntity).build();
    }
}
```

AuthorizationNeededInterface.java

```
package test.codehq.fab1.contexttest.cxf3test1;

import javax.ws.rs.NameBinding;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

@NameBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD})
public @interface AuthorizationNeededInterface
{

}
```

AuthorizationNeeded.java

```
package test.codehq.fab1.contexttest.cxf3test1;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ResourceContext;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;

@AuthorizationNeededInterface
@Provider
@Priority(1000)
public class AuthorizationNeeded implements ContainerRequestFilter
{
    @Context
    ResourceContext resourceContext;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext conRequestContext) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("DEBUG: IN FILTER");
        resourceContext.getResource(ContainerRequestContext.class).setProperty("AuthID", "1234");
    }
}
```

cxf-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><beans xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/soap.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd">
    <bean  id="ContextTestBean" class="test.codehq.fab1.contexttest.cxf3test1.ContextTest"/>
    <bean id="jsonProvider" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider"/>
    <bean id="AuthorizationNeededProvider" class="test.codehq.fab1.contexttest.cxf3test1.AuthorizationNeeded"/>

    <jaxrs:server id="cxf3test1Service" address="/cxf3test1">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref  bean="ContextTestBean"/>
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>

        <jaxrs:providers>
            <ref bean="jsonProvider" />
            <ref bean="AuthorizationNeededProvider" />
        </jaxrs:providers>

        <jaxrs:features>
            <cxf:logging/>
        </jaxrs:features>
    </jaxrs:server>
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>ContextTestCXF3test1</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <description>Apache CXF Endpoint</description>
        <display-name>cxf</display-name>
        <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>test.codinghq.fab1</groupId>
  <artifactId>ContextTestCXF3test1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-features-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-providers</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.7</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.21.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.21.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.21.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

When doing a request on the 'echos' resource i get the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Resource class interface javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext has no valid constructor
    org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.lifecycle.PerRequestResourceProvider.<init>(PerRequestResourceProvider.java:57)
    org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResourceContextImpl.getResource(ResourceContextImpl.java:50)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.tl.ThreadLocalInvocationHandler.invoke(ThreadLocalInvocationHandler.java:48)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1694.getResource(Unknown Source)
    test.codehq.fab1.contexttest.cxf3test1.AuthorizationNeeded.filter(AuthorizationNeeded.java:23)
    org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.runContainerRequestFilters(JAXRSUtils.java:1688)
```

Comment: You're not even using Jersey man. You are using CXF. You can't use both of them at the same time. Jersey supports the injection of the ContainerRequestContext, but this is not portable (it's not a feature of the JAX-RS specification). It is specific to the Jersey implementation. If you want to use Jersey instead of CXF, then you need to configure the Jersey servlet in your web.xml, not the CXF one (looks for examples for Jersey 1.x where the ServletContainer is declared as the <servlet-class>.

Comment: As an aside, please use Java naming convention; variable and method names begin with lowercase letters. Another aside, your resource classes are not supposed to have any of the following annotations: `@WebService`, `@XmlRootElement`, `@XmlAccessorType`, `@Provider`.

Comment: Thank you Paul for pointing out my cxf/jersey mistake. I have tried to convert the project to a Jersey based solution and in fact that works. I now have updated the code in my question to reflect the minor changes and also tried that for a CXF based solution. I can't get it to work. I'm getting the following error everytime a do a request on the 'echos' resource: java.lang.RuntimeException: Resource class interface javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext has no valid constructor

Answer (score 0):

> *UPDATE* I have solved the question. The code that doesn't work is still in this question so keep that in mind. I also posted the code of
>   the CXF and Jersey versions that do work. See those versions below the
>   dotted line. I think that in CXF the ContainerRequestContext is not available in a resource class. I don't know why Jersey makes this possible, but that just looks like the way they implemented it. I have found the solution by looking at an example from lefloh, [How to Pass Object from ContainerRequestFilter to Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866258/how-to-pass-object-from-containerrequestfilter-to-resource)
>   Thank you, lefloh for pointing out the fact that ContainerRequestFilter properties are synchronized with HttpServletRequest.

---

> CXF version (working)

ContextTest.java

```
package test.codehq.fab1.contexttest.cxf3test1;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.GenericEntity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@ManagedBean
@Path("/")
@Produces("application/json")
public class ContextTest
{
    // Keep in mind that the ContainerRequestContext
    // attributes are automatically synced with
    // HttpServletRequest. When using CXF the
    // ContainerRequestContext can not be directly
    // accessed in the Resource, so we need to use
    // HttpServletRequest 
    @Context
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

    public ContextTest()
    {

    }

    @AuthorizationNeededInterface
    @GET
    @Path("/echos/{echoRequestText}")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response echo(@PathParam("echoRequestText") String echoRequestText)
    {
        System.out.println("DEBUG: IN RESOURCE");

        Map<String, String> myResponse = new HashMap<String, String>();

        if(httpServletRequest != null)
        {
            if(httpServletRequest.getAttribute("AuthID") != null)
            {
                if(((String)httpServletRequest.getAttribute("AuthID")).compareTo("1234") == 0)
                {
                    myResponse.put("echo_response", echoRequestText);
                } 
                else myResponse.put("echo_response", "Invalid AuthID <1>");
            } 
            else myResponse.put("echo_response", "Invalid AuthID <2>");
        }
        else myResponse.put("echo_response", "Invalid AuthID <3>");

        GenericEntity<Map<String, String>> genericEntity = new GenericEntity<Map<String, String>>(myResponse){};
        return Response.ok().entity(genericEntity).build();
    }
}
```

AuthorizationNeededInterface.java

```
package test.codehq.fab1.contexttest.cxf3test1;

import javax.ws.rs.NameBinding;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

@NameBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD})
public @interface AuthorizationNeededInterface
{

}
```

AuthorizationNeeded.java

```
package test.codehq.fab1.contexttest.cxf3test1;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;

@AuthorizationNeededInterface
@Provider
@Priority(1000)
public class AuthorizationNeeded implements ContainerRequestFilter
{

    public AuthorizationNeeded()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext conRequestContext) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("DEBUG: IN FILTER");

        conRequestContext.setProperty("AuthID", "1234");
    }
}
```

cxf-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><beans xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/soap.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd">
    <bean  id="ContextTestBean" class="test.codehq.fab1.contexttest.cxf3test1.ContextTest"/>
    <bean id="jsonProvider" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider"/>
    <bean id="AuthorizationNeededProvider" class="test.codehq.fab1.contexttest.cxf3test1.AuthorizationNeeded"/>

    <jaxrs:server id="cxf3test1Service" address="/cxf3test1">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="ContextTestBean"/>
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>

        <jaxrs:providers>
            <ref bean="ContextTestBean"/>
            <ref bean="jsonProvider" />
            <ref bean="AuthorizationNeededProvider" />
        </jaxrs:providers>
    </jaxrs:server>
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>ContextTestCXF3test1</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <description>Apache CXF Endpoint</description>
        <display-name>cxf</display-name>
        <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>test.codinghq.fab1</groupId>
  <artifactId>ContextTestCXF3test1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-bundle-compatible</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-features-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-providers</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.7</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.21.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.21.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.21.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

> Jersey version (working)

ContextTest.java

```
package test.codehq.fab1.contexttest.jersey2test1;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ResourceContext;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.GenericEntity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/")
@Produces("application/json")
public class ContextTest
{
    @Context
    ResourceContext resourceContext;

    ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext;

    public ContextTest()
    {

    }

    @AuthorizationNeededInterface
    @GET
    @Path("/echos/{echoRequestText}")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response echo(@PathParam("echoRequestText") String echoRequestText)
    {
        System.out.println("DEBUG: IN RESOURCE");

        Map<String, String> myResponse = new HashMap<String, String>();

        containerRequestContext = resourceContext.getResource(ContainerRequestContext.class);

        if(containerRequestContext != null)
        {
            if(containerRequestContext.getProperty("AuthID") != null)
            {
                if(((String)containerRequestContext.getProperty("AuthID")).compareTo("1234") == 0)
                {
                    myResponse.put("echo_response", echoRequestText);
                } 
                else myResponse.put("echo_response", "Invalid AuthID <1>");
            } 
            else myResponse.put("echo_response", "Invalid AuthID <2>");
        }
        else myResponse.put("echo_response", "Invalid AuthID <3>");

        GenericEntity<Map<String, String>> genericEntity = new GenericEntity<Map<String, String>>(myResponse){};
        return Response.ok().entity(genericEntity).build();
    }
}
```

AuthorizationNeededInterface.java

```
package test.codehq.fab1.contexttest.jersey2test1;

import javax.ws.rs.NameBinding;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

@NameBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD})
public @interface AuthorizationNeededInterface
{

}
```

AuthorizationNeeded.java

```
package test.codehq.fab1.contexttest.jersey2test1;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ResourceContext;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;

@AuthorizationNeededInterface
@Provider
@Priority(1000)
public class AuthorizationNeeded implements ContainerRequestFilter
{
    @Context
    ResourceContext resourceContext;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext conRequestContext) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("DEBUG: IN FILTER");
        resourceContext.getResource(ContainerRequestContext.class).setProperty("AuthID", "1234");
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>ContextTestJersey2test1</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <description>Jersey Filter test</description>
    <display-name>contexttest-jersey2test1</display-name>
    <servlet-name>contexttest-jersey2test1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>test.codehq.fab1.contexttest.jersey2test1</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>contexttest-jersey2test1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>test.codinghq.fab1</groupId>
  <artifactId>ContextTestJersey2Test1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-providers</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.7</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.27</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-m05-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.27</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        <version>2.27</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.27</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```